# Get prop of an obj inside obj using string

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this obj here:

```
let obj1 ={
  a: 4,
  b: {
    ab: 44,
    c: {
      tres: 100
    }
  }
};
```

How can I access the **tres** property using a string? I can access **b** object using this code:

```
let prop = "b";
console.log(obj1[prop]); // returns b property
```

But how can I get access to a **tres** property that resides inside **c** inside **b** inside **obj1** object?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dot (`.`) operator to chain them on the computed property (`[prop]`) name:

```js
let obj1 ={
  a: 4,
  b: {
    ab: 44,
    c: {
      tres: 100
    }
  }
};


let prop = "b";
console.log(obj1[prop].c.tres);
```

Comment: _"How can I access the tres property **using a string**?"_

Comment: @Andreas, I believe OP wanted to mean `prop` as the string.